Was there supernetting before CIDR or were subnets restricted to their classes
Subnets before CIDR (introduced in 1993) sub-divided classful networks using subnets of class A, B and C.
With CIDR we can have arbitrary prefixes. For example, 192.0.0.0/7.
Could we have done that before CIDR (before 1993)?
Or were subnets restricted to their respective "classes of networks"?
If I had put an arbitrary subnet mask on say, Windows PC, would it stop me?

If I had put an arbitrary subnet mask on say, Windows PC, would it stop me? why not just try it?

not really a question for this area - I'd suggest Retrocomputing as a better home for this sort of question.

This reminds me of a funny interview question I used to ask newbies: can you assign addresses 192.168.0.255 and 192.168.1.0 to computers? Could they communicate using these addresses? How? (The answer is: yes, use the netmask /23 or wider. There were people who weren't believing this, so I sometimes even had to demonstrate this.)

So, in the past, you couldn't. There was no netmask field to specify, the netmask was embedded into the address — this is the core idea of classful addressing; 192 has embedded /24, and so on. When you specify address "192.168.1.1", it assumed a netmask of /24. Netmasks existed in context of firewalls and routers. Also, CIDR predates modern Windows TCP/IP stack; it was never classful.

It is possible to use 255 in a /24 subnet. Linux does not care about human-set limitation ;)

@NikitaKipriyanov: That's not entirely right – there was a long time between "fully CIDR" and "fully classful" during which subnetting existed, and I have seen more than one case of software that accepted addresses/netmasks only if they described subnets below a class boundary but not above it...

Indeed, and I have seen it too, despite the fact I came into the industry far later than CIDR emerged (1993, I can hardly understand why people still concerned about classful addressing). But that's a typical trait of software that was designed as classful and then extended to support CIDR. Funny enough, IPv6 is stepping on the same rake, with it's default 64-bit subnetting :)

@djdomi which is wrong and violates RFC2644 3. .255 in /24, or more generally, all-ones address (denoted as "-1" in the RFC) is reserved to be directed broadcast in all networks except /31 (exempted by RFC3021 2.2). That address must not be used as a source IP address, which means, it can't be assigned to a node. I think you meant .0 may be used as a node address? It was a broadcast too, but that's a long time obsolete.

@greg. Because I don’t have a pre-93 Windows lying around.

To answer the question, no, you could not have done this before CIDR in  1993.
Windows did not have a native tcpip stack, and other hosts (usually Unix) would not support it.
It probably depended on the third party tcpip stack that you could purchase for your platform, which was usually Windows. Novell had a stack for Windows that was very popular with businesses (in the US), and a DHCP server. Trumpet was a popular stack for Windows in 1994.
Someone even tried it for a few minutes.
https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18072/in-windows-3-11-did-a-unusual-subnet-mask-actually-work
RFC 1918 addressing was not common yet. Neither were firewalls. You basically used whatever public IP you were given for whatever host you were configuring. If you were security conscious, you could use an IP proxy with IPX on the  endpoints.
Most of the US government at that time was not on routable networks. Most of their networks were bridged. Routers were still new, and the first popular routers with small to medium business were dialup on demand or ISDN. So businesses were usually "endpoints" and used addresses/masks assigned to them.
